# Why does my 1000 millisecond timeout function take longer than a 1 second function?

Tags: javascript

I am writing a Javascript counter function but something that I am not quite sure.

Assume that 1000ms === 1s.

```js
    var ms = 0;
    var s = 0;

    setInterval(() => {document.querySelector('#ms').innerHTML = ms++}, 1);
    setInterval(() => {document.querySelector('#s').innerHTML = s++}, 1000);
```

```html
    <div id="ms">0</div>
    <div id="s">0</div>
```

Supposed that the speed of the millisecond function running from 0 to 1000 is the same as the second function running from 0 to 1, but the outcome seems that 1000ms !== 1s. Am I misunderstanding something about millisecond?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: All browsers have a minimum interval setting, which last time I checked was around 15ms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't work that way. When you define a timer (setTimeout or setInterval) the JS engine doesn't guarantee that it will run in 1,000 ms because it depends on what it's processing in the queue.

Also, the timer doesn't add a task in the queue if it already exists. This means that if the timer expires and there's already an instance in the queue for that timer, then it's not added again.

I recommend you this book: [https://www.amazon.com/dp/1617292850/?tag=stackoverflow17-20](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1617292850). It has a chapter about events and it explains exactly what you are asking.

Comment: Indeed, figure out a way of implementing a Delta time and multiply tick frames by that

Comment: Thanks Francisco, actually I want to write a function that when the ms reach 1000, then the second function add 1. Will take a look of the book you suggested and checked your answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

> Web browsers, like all applications, take turns for a piece of CPU
>   time, and the time they have to wait will vary, depending on the load.
>   This is what causes the latency in asynchronous timers — a 200ms timer
>   may actually take 202ms, or 204, and this will gradually send the
>   stopwatch out of time.
>
> The solution in this case is not to rely on the speed of the timer at
>   all, but rather, to query the system time freshly each loop and derive
>   the output from that.

Source: [Sitepoint](https://www.sitepoint.com/creating-accurate-timers-in-javascript/)